# Any Chart library for ASP CORE?

Tags: c#, charts, asp.net-core

Because of Project requirements, instead of using an HTML5 Canvas with JavaScript, I have to generate a chart/graph on an ASP.NET Core server.

The graph I need is quite simple, only Paint lines, so any basic opensource library compatible with C# ASP.NET Core could be enough.

I know System.Web.Helpers.Chart but I think is not compatible with C# ASP.NET Core.

Comment: I used using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting; for C# windows application for line chart.